# XML output with a Namespace within a Namespace using XMLMap

Tags: xml, sas

I need to create an XML output that is something like in the text below:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Requests>
    <RequestSetId>20170321</RequestSetId>
    <RequestStream>Anniversary</RequestStream>
    <ns0:Request xmlns:ns0="http://www.sample.com/xsd/BatchCenter_001">
        <ns0:TrackAndTrace>
            <ns0:CPAId>017</ns0:CPAId>
            <ns0:ConversationId>bd48928c-8f5e-4a3d-e85b-2c5d67a5f0d1</ns0:ConversationId>
            <ns0:EventId>4c8adceb-a48c-41b1-9ebc-a9d90507447e</ns0:EventId>
            <ns0:CorrelationId>e85b928c-8f5e-4a3d-bd48-2c5d67a5f0d1</ns0:CorrelationId>
        </ns0:TrackAndTrace>
        <ns2:SendCustomerMessage_001_Rq xmlns:ns2="http://www.sample.com/CustomerCommunication_001/SendCustomerMessage_001">
            <ns2:Location>
                <ns2:Purpose>ForceEmail</ns2:Purpose>
                <ns2:OutputProfile>HRM_OutputProfile_Batch</ns2:OutputProfile>
                <ns2:ContactForm>
                    <ns2:CustomerMessageAddress>
                        <ns2:EmailAddress>NAME.LASTNAME@EMAIL.COM</ns2:EmailAddress>
                    </ns2:CustomerMessageAddress>
                </ns2:ContactForm>
                <ns2:CommunicationDate>2017-03-20</ns2:CommunicationDate>
            </ns2:Location>
    </ns2:SendCustomerMessage_001_Rq>
    </ns0:Request>
    </Requests>
```

I used the sample XMLMap below and I'm getting misplaced end tag for the TrackAndTrace.

```
<TABLE description="Requests" name="Requests">
        <TABLE-PATH syntax="XPath">/Requests</TABLE-PATH>

        <COLUMN name="RequestSetId" retain="YES">
            <PATH syntax="XPath">/Requests/RequestSetId</PATH>
            <TYPE>character</TYPE>
            <DATATYPE>string</DATATYPE>
            <LENGTH>20</LENGTH>
        </COLUMN>

        <COLUMN name="RequestStream" retain="YES">
            <PATH syntax="XPathENR">/Requests/RequestSetId/RequestStream</PATH>
            <TYPE>character</TYPE>
            <DATATYPE>string</DATATYPE>
            <LENGTH>20</LENGTH>
        </COLUMN>

        <COLUMN name="CorrelationId">
            <PATH syntax="XPathENR">/Requests/{1}Request/{1}TrackAndTrace/{1}CorrelationId</PATH>
            <TYPE>character</TYPE>
            <DATATYPE>string</DATATYPE>
            <LENGTH>40</LENGTH>
        </COLUMN>

        <COLUMN name="EventId">
            <PATH syntax="XPathENR">/Requests/{1}Request/{1}TrackAndTrace/{1}EventId</PATH>
            <TYPE>character</TYPE>
            <DATATYPE>string</DATATYPE>
            <LENGTH>40</LENGTH>
        </COLUMN>

        <COLUMN name="ConversationId">
            <PATH syntax="XPathENR">/Requests/{1}Request/{1}TrackAndTrace/{1}ConversationId</PATH>
            <TYPE>character</TYPE>
            <DATATYPE>string</DATATYPE>
            <LENGTH>40</LENGTH>
        </COLUMN>

        <COLUMN name="CPAId">
            <PATH syntax="XPathENR">/Requests/{1}Request/{1}TrackAndTrace/{1}CPAId</PATH>
            <TYPE>character</TYPE>
            <DATATYPE>string</DATATYPE>
            <LENGTH>8</LENGTH>
        </COLUMN>

<COLUMN name="Purpose">
            <PATH syntax="XPathENR">/Requests/{1}Request/{2}SendCustomerMessage_001_Rq/{2}Location/{2}Purpose</PATH>
            <TYPE>character</TYPE>
            <DATATYPE>string</DATATYPE>
            <LENGTH>10</LENGTH>
        </COLUMN>

        <COLUMN name="OutputProfile">
            <PATH syntax="XPathENR">/Requests/{1}Request/{2}SendCustomerMessage_001_Rq/{2}Location/{2}OutputProfile</PATH>
            <TYPE>character</TYPE>
            <DATATYPE>string</DATATYPE>
            <LENGTH>25</LENGTH>
        </COLUMN>

        <COLUMN name="CommunicationDate">
            <PATH syntax="XPathENR">/Requests/{1}Request/{2}SendCustomerMessage_001_Rq/{2}Location/{2}CommunicationDate</PATH>
            <TYPE>numeric</TYPE>
            <DATATYPE>date</DATATYPE>
            <FORMAT width="10">IS8601DA</FORMAT>
            <INFORMAT width="10">IS8601DA</INFORMAT>
        </COLUMN>

        <COLUMN name="EmailAddress">
            <PATH syntax="XPathENR">/Requests/{1}Request/{2}SendCustomerMessage_001_Rq/{2}Location/{2}ContactForm/{2}CustomerMessageAddress/{2}EmailAddress</PATH>
            <TYPE>character</TYPE>
            <DATATYPE>string</DATATYPE>
            <LENGTH>100</LENGTH>
        </COLUMN>

    </TABLE>
</SXLEMAP>
```

This is the code I used to output the xml:

```
libname XML 'C:\test_XML\XML';

filename out 'C:\test_XML\XML\Requests.xml';

libname out xml92 xmltype=xmlmap xmlmap='C:\test_XML\XMLMAP\req_map.map';

data out.Requests;
    set XML.requests;
run;
```

[image: Added the table I used to create the xml, please don't mind the RequestId column as I only use it for additional tests]
Can you please help me where I went wrong with this. Thank you in advance.

Regards,
Angel

Comment: You're missing a bunch from that map (including the namespaces) to the point that you're not going to get much helpful unfortunately.

Comment: Can you please explain more what I'm missing? I don't have an XML Mapper to generate it automatically so it's a rough draft.

Comment: @Joe, Can you please give me more explanation? I really need to fix this. Thanks

Comment: If you're trying to write that XML file from an existing SAS dataset, I would suggest putting in details about the SAS dataset into the question.  I'd also suggest taking it slow - start with a map that just puts one variable, then add complexity until eventually you get to the final map.

Comment: Yes, please post SAS dataset sample and your attempted code for a reproducible example. The highs and lows of StackOverflow (sigh). Posters tease and tantalize with an interesting question but not enough info to get started.

Comment: Edited my question and added the script I use to output the xml as well as the source table. I already tried doing what you've said @Joe. When I used only one namespace, the TrackandTrace end tag were placed correctly. But when adding the SendCustomerMessage_001_Rq tag, the TrackandTrace end tag is goes to the CPAId.